# Arduino Memory - static

Tags: memory, static, arduino, constants

I have few question to the arduino memory.

1. Does it make sense to move global Variables, a single int, with PROGMEM in the Flash Memory or does that the Compiler for me?
   Or should I declare the global variable 
   "#define" instead "static const int xy =..."
2. A static Variable in the loop function
   Example:

   void loop()
   {
    static unsigned short Array [] = {Global_Variable_1,  Global_Variable_2,...}
   }

Where is that Variable "Array" stored? Is it right that it is stored only in the SRAM?

Answer (score 0):

For 1)
For an int, using PROGMEM is not need.
Compiler won't do it for you.
`#define` is not a global, `#define` can't be edited, it's just a macros handle by precompiler, so a `#define` don't use any memory

for 2) Array is a global so it is stored in the data segment of the prog, it will be loaded in SRAM to be used at run time if you use PROGMEM it will be stored into flash memory